# How do I create an SVG polygon with uniform stroke width?

Tags: html, css, svg, geometry

I am trying to create an SVG polygon with a border round the element (or in this case a stroke). This works for the most part however the clipped edges of the polygon appear to have a thicker stroke than the other sides. Is there a way to ensure that the stroke width is uniform round the shape.

Here's an image illustrating the problem [image]

The top left and bottom right edge have a visibly thicker stroke than the other sides or edges.

The code is basically this

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 100" height="500" width="500">
  <polygon points="10, 0, 100, 0, 100, 90, 90, 100, 0, 100, 0, 10" style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:4" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The stroke really is `4` units wide, but it's being clipped by the viewbox. Remember that strokes are centred along their path rather than aligned to one side...

...so if you have a viewbox of `0 0 100 100` and you have a line or path running from `(0,0)` to `(0,100)` and you give it a stroke of `7px`, then only `3.5px` of that stroke's width will be visible because the other half will exist between `x = -3.5px` and `x = 0`.

If you increase the size of the viewbox and/or move the `polygon` so its points are at least `4` "units" away from the side of the viewbox then the full path becomes visible:

(It's `4` "units" and not `4px` because unitless widths (like `stroke-width: 4;`) [in SVG are assumed to be in units of the viewbox w.r.t. the current set of transformations, if relevant](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#Units) - so you might want to add an explicit unit to the `stroke-width` property for consistent rendering.

```html
<svg viewbox="-5 -5 110 110" height="500" width="500">
  <polygon points="10, 0, 100, 0, 100, 90, 90, 100, 0, 100, 0, 10" style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:4" />
</svg>
```

Comment: You are not correct that unitless widths are %'s of the canvas size. Unit-less widths are assumed to be  userSpaceOnUse units - which are viewBox units adjusted by whatever the current transform stack is. Details: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#Units. In this case - it's only 4% because the viewBox has established 0-100 as the scale for the horizontal axis - which only happens to correspond to 4%. In SVG 1.1 there are only two unit types - userSpaceOnUse and objectBoundingBox and other unit types (pt, vh etc.) are only supported to size the SVG element itself.

Comment: @MichaelMullany Thank you for the feedback! I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"` would solve this for you, like:

```
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 100" height="500" width="500">
  <polygon vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" 
           points="10, 0, 100, 0, 100, 90, 90, 100, 0, 100, 0, 10" style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:4" />
</svg>
```